# How to get predicted labels during training of any classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there any way that I can track my model's performance in terms of it's classified labels, *during the training phase*? Any classifier from `sklearn` would work as an example.

To be more specific, I want to get something like a list of Confusion Matrices here:

```py
clf = LinearSVC(random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)
# ... here ...
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

My objective here is to see how well the model is learning (during training). This is similar to analyzing the training loss, that is a common practice in DNN's, and libraries such as pyTorch, Keras, and Tensorflow have such capability already implemented.

---

I thought a quick browsing of the web would give me what I want, but apparently not. I still believe this should be fairly simple though.

Answer (score 0):

Some ML practitioners like to work with three folds of data: training, validation and testing sets. The latter should not be seen in any training at all, but the middle could. For example, cross-validation uses K different folds of validation sets "during the training phase" to get a less biased performance estimation when training with different parts of the data.

But you can do this on a single validation fold for the purpose of what you asked.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
X_train2, X_valid, y_train2, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2)

# Fit a classifier with train data only
clf = LinearSVC(random_state=42).fit(X_train2, y_train2)
y_valid_pred = clf.predict(X_valid)
confusionm_valid = confusion_matrix(y_valid, y_valid_pred) # ... here ...

# Refit with all your training data
clf = LinearSVC(random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_valid)
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not give me what I want. I added some more explanation to my question. I would like to monitor the training process right when the model is trying to adjust its loss until it meets some criteria, and not after that.

Comment: Ok. From what I know, this cannot be retrieved with a single approach for all estimators. However, as you mentioned DNNs, sklearn's MLPClassifier does have a `.loss_curve_` attribute with what you want.